# PAULI_CHANNEL_2 decomposition with zero prob for single qubit cases

Tags: stim

Why does the [code associated with the paper "Benchmarking the Planar Honeycomb Code"](https://github.com/Strilanc/honeycomb-boundaries/blob/cc33baac44c7831bd643db81d0053f8ec6eae9d8/src/hcb/tools/gen/noise.py#L256) set some `PAULI_CHANNEL_2` errors to tiny values?

```
# make single qubit cases non-zero for decomposition
pxi = pix = pyi = piy = piz = pzi = 1E-15
```

What happens if they are 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stim converts a circuit into a detector error model, this process often produces models with errors that have more than 2 symptoms. This is a problem for matching based decoders because they only understand errors with at most 2 symptoms. To work around this issue, [`stim.Circuit.detector_error_model`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.detector_error_model) can be given an argument `decompose_errors=True` which requests that complex errors with more than 2 symptoms should be split into pieces that only have 2 symptoms.

One of the cardinal rules that the error decomposition logic follows is that, when breaking things into pieces, it **must only use pieces that appear as errors elsewhere in the model**. This is a safety feature, to ensure the decomposition doesn't accidentally violate some crucial invariant the errors are supposed to follow, like Z detection events always appearing in pairs in the bulk of a surface code.

The code you linked is including those error mechanisms with tiny probabilities because it wants the error decomposition to decompose into them. If the probabilities were set to 0, the decomposition would be forbidden from decomposing into them. But in this case they are actually the correct thing to decompose into. So we set the error rates to a super low non-zero value to indicate the decomposition is allowed, without distorting the intended noise model too much.